# write a batch file to get a directory of text files/ search for a specific token and insert a line after that

Tags: batch-file

I need to read a bunch of text files from a folder. find a specific token such as "Corolla" for each text file and insert a new line after the token. 
Suppose the text file is like:

```
first line
second line
a part of third line, Corolla, third line remaining
INSERT THE NEW LINE HERE
the rest of file.
```

I am very new to batch files and it is challenging for me.

Thanks

Partial Answer:

I could use the following code, but this code only finds the token if the whole line has that token. I also needs to find the token if it is between some sentences as well (substring)!

```
@echo off
set SrcFolder=C:\Input
set DstFolder=C:\Output
for %%a in ("%SrcFolder%\*.txt") do (
  (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%h in ("%%a") do (
    echo.%%h
    if "%%h" equ "Corolla" (
      echo THE NEW LINE
    )
  ))>"%DstFolder%\%%~nxa"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of

```
     "%%h" equ "Corolla" (
```

(which should yield an error anyway)

put

```
 echo %%h|findstr "Corolla" >nul&if not errorlevel 1 (
```

which looks for the literal "Corolla" in each line, setting `errorlevel` to `0` if found. Do not try `if errorlevel 0` because `findstr` will always set `errorlevel` to a positive integer and the `if errorlevel` test tests for `errorlevel` being n **or greater than n**

Comment: Thre should be a space between `findstr` and `"Corolla"`.

Comment: Can I find a combination of tokens as well with findstr? suppose that if I want to do the above if I find corolla and matrix in a line: such as BLAH BLAH COROLLA BLAH BLAH MATRIX –

Comment: Also, is it possible to have the "THE NEW LINE" with a counter? Suppose I have 4 "Corolla" in text files and I need the "The NEW LINE" be like:  "THE 1 NEW LINE", "The 2 NEW LINE", "The 3 NEW Line" ,...

Comment: Alternatively: `echo %%h|findstr "Corolla" && (`. Anyway, why would `"%%h" equ "Corolla"` generate an error? Seems a legitimate condition and the syntax right. What am I missing?

Comment: @Bipario: That "insert multiple lines" problem might make a nice *new* question. (But please don't use a lengthy title, just let it reflect the problem at hand.)

Comment: @AndriyM: The original post has been edited to include the missing `if`

Comment: Ah, that's silly of me. I read your statement while editing the question and so the indication of the question's having been edited was hidden at that time. (Don't know why it didn't occur to me to take a look at the revision history anyway, so stupid.) Thanks.

Comment: To vary the text inserted, you would need to invoke delayedexpansion or call a subroutine. Quite how would really need to be a new question, but be sure to specify when the variant part of the inserted text is to change. For instance, it may be changed on encountering each "Corolla" in the entire operation (first time, 1;second, 2 etc.) or it may change for each file (within file x, each "Corolla" is followed by x) or it may reset for each file (so the first "Corolla" in file x has 1, he second has 2 and then in file y we start again at 1).

Comment: Magoo, I need it to be variant for entire operation. I do not care if it happens in one specific file or not. So I opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861339/insert-a-variant-string-in-text-with-bat-file

Comment: New Question: Is it possible to just replace the file with new one instead of storing a new file in "DstFolder" ?

Comment: Not directly. You need to create a new file, then `move /y "newfile" "oldfile"