# Insert a variant string in text files by creating a bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem which is a subset of a solved problem in [write a batch file to get a directory of text files/ search for a specific token and insert a line after that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845554/write-a-batch-file-to-get-a-directory-of-text-files-search-for-a-specific-token).

I need to read a bunch of text files from a folder. find a specific token such as "Corolla" for each text file and insert a new line with a variant after the token. Suppose the text file is like:

```
first line
second line
a part of third line, Corolla, third line remaining
INSERT THE NEW LINE Number 1 HERE
a part of forth line, Corolla, firth line remaining
INSERT THE NEW LINE Number 2 HERE
The rest of file.
```

and do this operation for other files in the folder as well. Also I do not want the variant to be reset for each file. Suppose that Corolla is found in the second file so the variant should start at 3.

The solution to non-variant version is:

```
@echo off
set SrcFolder=C:\Input
set DstFolder=C:\Output
for %%a in ("%SrcFolder%\*.txt") do (
  (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%h in ("%%a") do (
    echo.%%h
    echo %%h|findstr "Corolla" >nul&if not errorlevel 1 (
      echo THE NEW LINE
    )
  ))>"%DstFolder%\%%~nxa"
)
```

But I need to add the variant as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set SrcFolder=C:\Input
set DstFolder=C:\Output
set Variant=0
for %%a in ("%SrcFolder%\*.txt") do (
  (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%h in ("%%a") do (
    echo.%%h
    echo %%h|findstr "Corolla" >nul&if not errorlevel 1 (
      set /a "Variant+=1"
      setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
      echo THE NEW LINE !Variant!
      endlocal
    )
  ))>"%DstFolder%\%%~nxa"
)
```

Comment: New Question: Is it possible to just replace the file with new one instead of storing a new file in "DstFolder" ? Thanks

Comment: @Bipario, `move /y "%DstFolder%\%%~nxa" "%%~fa"` after file creation, just before the closing parenthesis in the outer `for` loop.

Comment: I see. You  overwrote the new files to the old locations. Thanks it works. But I just wanted to expand this problem for subdirectories as well. Suppose that the source folder has some subdirectories with some text files. Is it still possible to catch those text files as well?

Comment: I could solve the problem by using this command: for  /R c:\Input\  %%a in ("*.txt") do (